# jquery .blur for entire block of HTML

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML item for a 'drop down menu', structured like this...

```
            <li class="ui-dropdown-list" >
                <a href="#">Right Drop Down Menu</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Using jQuery to make this a dropdown list, with the following code.

```
jQuery.fn.dropdown = function () {

    var defaults = {
        button: null,
        menu: null,
        visible: false
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        options.button = $(this);
        options.menu = $(this).find("ul");

        // when the parent is clicked, determine whether dropdown needs to occur
        options.button.click(function () {
            options.visible ? lift(options.menu) : drop(options.menu);
            options.visible = !options.visible;
        });

        // drop the menu down so that it can be seen.
        function drop(e) {
            options.button.addClass("open");
            options.menu.show();
        }
        // lift the menu up, hiding it from view.
        function lift(e) {
            options.menu.hide();
            options.button.removeClass('open');
        }

    });
};
```

I am trying to wire it up so that if the user clicks anywhere outside of the menu, it will collapse it. This is proving much more difficult than I anticipated; even trying to use page level events. Any suggestions?

The menu itself never really 'receives' focus, so using .blur doesn't seem to be suiting the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event bubbling to your advantage here, if a `click` event bubbles all the way to `document` then close the menus, if it happens in the menu, stop the bubble so that handler on `document` doesn't get hit, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.dropdown = function () {
    var defaults = {
        button: null,
        menu: null,
        visible: false
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        options.button = $(this);
        options.menu = $(this).find("ul");
        $(document).click(lift); //close on bubble!

        options.button.click(function (e) {
            options.menu.is(':visible') ? lift() : drop();
            e.stopPropagation(); //prevent bubble!
        });

        function drop(e) {
            options.button.addClass("open");
            options.menu.show();
        }
        function lift(e) {
            options.menu.hide();
            options.button.removeClass('open');
        }
    });
};
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8LMwn/2/) :)

Comment: This works pretty well, but what about if I need to fire events when they click the links in the ul?

Comment: Oh wow, this works perfectly. I figured the link thing out. this jsfiddle thing is INCREDIBLE...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** See Nick Craver's answer for a full example of utilizing event bubbling.

---

Perhaps another approach would be to have a text `input` with its opacity set to zero that receives focus when you expand the menu, and fires a blur handler to collapse the menu.

Of course, it will fire if you click a menu item as well.

A little more hackish perhaps, but a little more focused event handler at the same time.

---

**EDIT:**

While messing with Nick's jsFiddle example, I tried creating two menus. It didn't function properly because both instances were sharing the same set of `options`.

If you plan on having more than one menu, I think you'll want to place the variable that stores the `options` within the `each()` function, so that each menu has its own set.

```
jQuery.fn.dropdown = function () {

    var defaults = {
        button: null,
        menu: null,
        visible: false
    };

    return this.each(function () {
           // each menu gets its own options
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        options.button = $(this);
        options.menu = $(this).find("ul");

 ...and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to close the menu if the user clicks outside of it, for that I've had a similar problem in January, and came up with this:

```
document.onclick=check;
function check(e){
    var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
    var obj = document.getElementById('opts_select01');
    var obj2 = document.getElementById('select01_input');
    checkParent(target)?obj.style.display='none':null;
    target==obj2?obj.style.display='block':null;
}
function checkParent(t){
    while(t.parentNode){
        if(t==document.getElementById('opts_select01')){
            return false;
        }
        t=t.parentNode;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What it does is detect the mouse click, and if the mouse clicks outside the two specified elements, it will set the display of the menu to "none", therefor hiding it!

I've used this code to show a div when a user clicks on an input (to create a custom select-box, that became really popular) :)
either way, if it's open and the user clicks on the div or the input, it stays open, but if click goes somewhere else on the page, it closes the div!
Plus, if the user clicks the input (that's always visible) when the div is hidden, it will trigger the div (showing it)

For you, replace the "select01_input" by an ID of a menu element that's always visible (used to trigger the menu), and replace the "opts_select01" by an ID of the menu tree.

> To close it completely, the easy way
>   is to hide the entire menu through css
>   display property...

Hope it helps U!